# How do you select a range of lines in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do you select a range of lines (from a start line number to an end line number) in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Actually this is *not* a programming question. Maybe ask at superuser.com.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Click at the first column of the first line. Then scroll down to the last line that you want to select, HOLD Shift key and click on the last line.

Comment: Is there a key binding that allows you to do this with input?

Comment: This might work for a small amount of lines, but if the number of lines is huge @Akshay Gaur solution would be better to use

Comment: Better answer ITT: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63931411/838517

Comment: Oh myyy. thank you. I've literally been scrolling and deleting since yesterday and when I couldn't bear it any longer, I had to say there must be a way. Thank you

Answer (score 59):

I had to delete lines starting from line number 17158 through 1644546 which was nearly impossible to do if I used scrolling. So I followed 4 simple steps:

1. Go the line where you want to start deleting (17158 in my case).
2. Using keyboard, press `Ctrl+G` which opens a box to enter the line number to go to.
3. Enter the line number in the box (1644546 in my case). VS Code will take you to the line you wanted to go to.
4. Hold the shift key and click on the line. Hopefully, this should select all the lines that you wanted to delete.

Comment: this is actually a good solution for the above specific need. +1

Comment: Better answer ITT: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63931411/838517

Comment: i almost instantly deleted lines 17158 to 1644546 from a large file from the command line with `sed -i '17158,1644546d' <insert_filename_path>`. see https://linuxhandbook.com/remove-lines-file/

Answer (score 45):

Since version 1.46 it seems like you can set an anchor and select from anchor to cursor: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_46#_accessibility

- First set a selection anchor (default binding Ctrl+K Ctrl+B)
- Then go to the line that you want, either by mouse or by Go To Line command
- Then **Select From Anchor to Cursor** (default binding Ctrl+K Ctrl+K)

To cancel selection hit `esc`.

Comment: This should be also one of the accepted answers, using just the keyboard

Comment: Perfect, wanted to just use the keyboard. Thanks!

Comment: I have tried most of the tricks, but only this one works for me.

Answer (score 5):

Try this out...
Type #region at the start of the line which you want to select and #endregion at the end of the line and collapse it using the side ruler available in VS code .Now since it will in a single region you can select the region easily

Answer (score -1):

Hi y'all I found a really fun way to do it. Ctrl-= will select to the last go back.